# PostgreSQL regexp_replace square brackets to other format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this column text in a table which contains following string

```json
{
  "person": {
    "id": "b01d9bf1-998f-4fa8-879a-0f8d0de4b626",
    "creationDate": [
      2022,
      1,
      22
    ],    
    "modificationDate": [
      2022,
      1,
      27
    ]
  }
}
```

I have the following regexp_matches query:

```sql
select regexp_matches('"creationDate": [2022,1,22], "modificationDate": [2022,1,27],', '\[(.[^)]+)\]', 'g')
```

but I need to replace

```json
"creationDate": [2022,1,22], "modificationDate": [2022,1,27],
```

to

```json
"creationDate": "2022-01-22", "modificationDate": "2022-01-27",
```

I'm not very good working with regular expressions. Also the difficulty is in adding a leading zero to the month as you can see.

Comment: Don't use a regex, use the JSON functions to change the value. And the column shouldn't be defined as `text` if it stores JSON, it should be `jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

**Regex-based**

A nested regex replacement does the trick:

```
select regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(
        '"creationDate": [2022,1,22], "modificationDate": [2022,1,27],'
      , '\[(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\]'
      , '"\1-\2-\3"'
      , 'g'
    )
  , '-(\d)-'
  , '-0\1-'
  , 'g');
```

The outer replacement only fires if the month is represented by a single digit.

**JSON-based**

Dwelling on the comment by @a_horse_with_no_name, the following query operates uses json operators:

```
    select x.key
         , (x.value ->> 0) || '-' || LPAD(x.value ->> 1, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD(x.value ->> 2, 2, '0') mydate
      from json_each ( '{"creationDate": [2022,1,22], "modificationDate": [2022,1,27] }'::json ) x
         ;
```

The query builds a set of records from a JSON object consisting of a key (the JSON property name) and a value of the native JSON datatype, which happens to be an array. The array elements are extracted, padded with leading zeros where appropriate and concatenated.

See the [Postgresql docs for JSON operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html) for more info.

***Full-fledged example***

Query to produce a recordset of persons containing their id plus the creation and modification date based on a json array of objects as given in the question.

```
        select id
             , ("creationDate" ->> 0)     || '-' || LPAD("creationDate"     ->> 1, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD("creationDate"     ->> 2, 2, '0')  creation_date
             , ("modificationDate" ->> 0) || '-' || LPAD("modificationDate" ->> 1, 2, '0') || '-' || LPAD("modificationDate" ->> 2, 2, '0')  modification_date
          from jsonb_to_recordset (
                    (
                      select jsonb_path_query_array ( orig.j, '$.person' ) part
                        from (
                                select '[
                                           { "person": { "id": "b01d9bf1-998f-4fa8-879a-0f8d0de4b626", "creationDate": [2022,1,22], "modificationDate": [2022,1,27] } }
                                         , { "person": { "id": "deadcafe-998f-4fa8-879a-0f8d0de4b626", "creationDate": [2000,1,1], "modificationDate": [2000,12,31] } }
                                       ]'::jsonb j
                             ) orig
                    )
               ) as x( id varchar(50), "creationDate" json, "modificationDate" json ) 
             ;
```

Available live [here (dbfiddle.co.uk)](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ea296423cda894c3ecc278acc4016135).